# Placement of adjective "concerned"

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis

Are

```
Pass the files to the concerned person
```

and

```
Pass the files to the person concerned
```

the same?

I was told the first one means "worried person."

Comment: You were told right.

Comment: Answered at [Can adjectives be placed without a noun after them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31009/can-adjectives-be-placed-without-a-noun-after-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you were told right as you can see in the examples below:

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/concerned

1 worried about something

*Concerned parents held a meeting to discuss the issue.*

2 [NEVER BEFORE NOUN] involved in something, or affected by something

*I suggest you have a quick word with the person concerned.*
*It was a difficult time for all concerned* (=for everyone who was involved).

They are definitely NOT the same.

Comment: Hello, Oyana. This is general reference (just doing easy research for someone_, and has been addressed before.